# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have no clue why I am getting this error, I believe the logic is fine.

matchData[0] contains this information:

```
{    players: ["Disguised Lizard", "DrSpiteful"],
    winner: "DrSpiteful",
    scoreDifference: 1
}
```

Here's the logic containing Match(props) info:

```
import React from 'react';
import Match from './Match';
import matchData from '../data/matchData';

function MatchList(props) {
  const oneMatch = matchData[0];
  console.log(oneMatch);
  return (
    <section className="PlayerList MatchList">
      <h1>Match list</h1>
      <Match
        players={oneMatch.players}
        winner={oneMatch.winner}
        scoreDifference={oneMatch.scoreDifference}
        />
    </section>
  );
}

export default MatchList;
```

I am getting an issue with this line of             `{props.players[0]} <span>vs</span> {props.players[1]}` extracted from the code below:

```
import React from 'react';

function Match(props) {
  return (
    <article className="Match">
      <h1>
        {props.players[0]} <span>vs</span> {props.players[1]}
      </h1>
      {/* To be shown when there is a winner */}
      <h2>
        {props.winner} is the winner by {props.scoreDifference}!
      </h2>
      {/* To be shown when there is no winner */}
      <h2>No winners yet!</h2>
    </article>
  );
}

export default Match;
```

Can anyone point out to me what I am doing wrong, I honestly don't see the issue.

Comment: after <h1> do a console.log(props.players). Do you see an undefined somewhere in your console?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that earlier and it's returning both players, but I want to access the index 0 of the players array and index 1

Comment: The console.log(props.players[0]) returns "Disguised Lizard" which is good but for some reason my react app is not liking it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code. I hope this code will help you.

```
props[players][0]
```

Comment: I have tried the brackets notation earlier but it still returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

*** EDIT:
I have decided to not access the data directly with the index and instead used a loop ***

There seems to be an issue with React.

when I console log

```
{console.log(props.players[0])} <span>vs</span> {console.log(props.players[1])}
```

It returns the appropriate information:

Disguised Lizard vs DrSpiteful

However, my react app just crashes and says:

```
Match.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

Comment: Your code as posted looks correct.  Are you perhaps calling MatchList or Match in some sort of loop that has an off by one error ?  It's unlikely that there is an issue with React for something so fundamenatl.

Comment: the MatchList is getting info directly from the DB file ( another JS file in a different folder", so I am not accessing the data with the help of a loop and both files are not being called by a loop either. I honestly don't know why it's causing this error. The console logs are returning the correct value but React App doesn't render the page and won't load.

Answer (score -1):

Hope it works.
{props.players.length == 0 ? "" : props.players[0]} vs {props.players.length == 0 ? "" : props.players[1]}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).